# [iOS]renew push certificate but don't have certificateSigningRequest file

Tags: ios, jenkins, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, app-store

I need to renew my push certificate but don't have the production certificateSigningRequest file anymore.

Does the app distribution and push certificate need the same certificateSigningRequest to work ?

How to go about without creating a new CSR/App signing certificate/ push certificate, without affecting old app updates and such that old apps still receive push.

Should the jenkins/ci signing certificate need to be replaced too or old certificates work until revoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the app distribution and push certificate need the same certificateSigningRequest to work ?

**NO!** There is no need to be the same `certificateSigningRequest` for both. It will perfectly works with a new certificate signing request, please go with it!

Comment: and will the previous push certificate still work unless it expires/we revoke it ?